# Can a highly experimental paper with potentially controversial concepts published on a preprint server (not in a journal) damage one's career?

Tags: publications, preprint

Imagine a paper which has unconventional ideas which could be controversial. Does publishing it on a preprint server have the same negative career implications as publishing in a journal? Or is a preprint server actually an appropriate place to get feedback on this type of paper?

Comment: Are we talking unconventional like I think a commonly accepted model is wrong, or unconventional like the lizard people that run the journals are out to get me because I know the truth about 5G?

Comment: More like I think a commonly accepted model is wrong. Specifically, an application for a statistical measure which it normally is not used for. (Although it wouldn't challenge existing applications)

Comment: Why would "an application for a statistical measure which it normally is not used for" be controversial? What is the kind of criticism you expect?

Comment: I do not see how this could be answered without reading the paper.

Answer (score 4):

> Imagine a paper which has unconventional ideas which could be controversial. Does publishing it on a preprint server have the same negative career implications as publishing in a journal?

Yes, potentially. You are making your thoughts and beliefs about a certain subject known publicly. Depending on what those thoughts and beliefs are, this can damage one’s career even if done in a tweet, email, stack exchange post (hmm...) or any other medium of expression. A preprint server is no different.

> Or is a preprint server actually an appropriate place to get feedback on this type of paper?

A preprint server is an appropriate place to get feedback on scientific work that’s maybe incomplete but is very close to being complete. Nonetheless, the potential for career damage if the work is of very low quality or reveals you to be a delusional or incompetent person still exists. If that is a concern, consider looking for feedback in more discreet ways.

Comment: ... or writing it inside a matchbook cover and leaving it on the bar or ...

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue of presenting ‘unconventional’ and ‘controversial’ ideas is irrelevant. The question is- what benefit or risks are involved when any paper is put on a preprint server.

Best case-you get solid feedback and your manuscript improves.

Worst case-your competitors get a chance to scoop you or prepare eviscerating review that perhaps could be used if said competitors are asked to review your paper.

Why not take traditional approach of sending preprint to your colleagues and adversaries officially, thereby getting their thoughts while also eliminating them as potential referees?

Comment: Worser case - people in your field that you want to hire you for a job in the future recognize you as a crank and avoid hiring you.